# Does Chromium pass URLs along with JS to V8?

Tags: javascript, chromium, v8

I've added a print statement to v8/src/parsing/parsing.cc to output JS source code before compilation to deobfuscate code. I also want to print the URL associated with the JS if it exists.

There are objects, such as source_url, in parser.cc and scanner.cc that and would appreciate advice about extracting the URL from them if they actually contain that information.

If they don't contain JS source URLs where should I look elsewhere in Chromium source code?

Comment: What do you mean by "*to deobfuscate code*"? It's not quite clear what your goal is.

Comment: To me, it looks a lot like you are posting [XY Problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You ask a question-chain about how to add some printing into V8, when it appears you want to obtain source code from websites in order to deobfuscate them.

Comment: This might be a question for v8-dev.

Comment: Using jmrk's advice, parsing.cc prints each stage of recursively obfuscated JS.

For instance, ofuscate some arbitrary JS
   ex: console.log("This is a test, it is only a test."); 
using the https :// github .com/ iWinston/javascript-code-protection-example/tree/master

The print statement D8 prints each step:

   3a. ..."var _0x1637=['C    ...   @6&D'));"

   3b. ...(function() {}.constructor("return this")( ));\x0a})"

   3c. ...(function anonymous(\x0a) {\x0areturn this\x0a})"

   This is a test, it is only a test.

Printing the URL helps identify target JS in Chromium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `source_url` that the scanner passes to the parser only reflects explicit "sourceURL" comments in the source; any code that needs deobfuscation probably won't have those.

To get the script URL, you'll want to look at `v8::internal::Script::name()`. It can be a `v8::internal::String`, or `undefined` if the embedder (i.e. Chromium) didn't provide a name for the given script -- which can in particular happen when the script doesn't *have* a name/URL, such as when it comes from the DevTools console or a dynamically-generated source string.